# Coming with this laravel sql privilege any good solution?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am getting error while laravel try to access mysql it says like this

```
   ` enter code here
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: sele  
          ct * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = blog and table_nam  
          e = migrations) 
In Connector.php line 67:

          SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' `enter code here`
`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem related to laravel itself. Check the DB-related [`.env`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#environment-configuration) settings. There are usually similar to this:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=default
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

Comment: i already did that ..but prob still continues even my workbench cant connect to mysql.

Comment: @mohnishgarg Then it's not Laravel. You have the wrong credentials - username, password, or perhaps it doesn't permit access from your IP.

Comment: but i can enter mysql account with root and password .....then why localhost@root have not privilege i even grant privilege

Comment: Look, if you can't connect with Workbench, your problem is beyond Laravel. What tool are you using to "enter mysql account with root and password" successfully? The command line?

Comment: ya commant line .. of mysql server

Comment: successfully done with this problem problem was with the php drivers that php7 was not having. I just need to install driver by  **sudo apt-get install php-mysql **